# Select and Label on one row bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm try to set label and select on one row, but it doesn't work not work, i'm also add "col" class, but it's makes it's uneven.

```
<div class="row">
    <h3>Language </h3>
    <select class="form-control">
        <option value="CSharp">C#</option>
        <option value="CPP">C++</option>
        <option value="XML">XML</option>
        <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
        <option value="SQL">SQL</option>
        <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to soround your form group with a form that has the attribute inline. Also, h3 basically makes a break after the content, you need either to set it to display: inline or in my opinion the better solution would be to use a label.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Language </label>
    <select class="form-control">
      <option value="CSharp">C#</option>
      <option value="CPP">C++</option>
      <option value="XML">XML</option>
      <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
      <option value="SQL">SQL</option>
      <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

a quick fix to problem is wrap the select around label

HTML

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Language 
        <select class="form-control">
            <option value="CSharp">C#</option>
            <option value="CPP">C++</option>
            <option value="XML">XML</option>
            <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
            <option value="SQL">SQL</option>
            <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.form-group label {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.form-group select {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

example here [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/RRdOJE)

enjoy.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```css
.col-md-6 > h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 0
}
select.form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>Language </h3>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option value="CSharp">C#</option>
            <option value="CPP">C++</option>
            <option value="XML">XML</option>
            <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
            <option value="SQL">SQL</option>
            <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
        </select>
        </div> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <span>Language </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
  <select class="form-control">
        <option value="CSharp">C#</option>
        <option value="CPP">C++</option>
        <option value="XML">XML</option>
        <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
        <option value="SQL">SQL</option>
        <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Using grid this can be done [codepen](http://codepen.io/eraditya123/pen/EyrJzQ?editors=1010)